# How to linearize Qr[i] = Q[i] * Z[i]

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I want to linearly modelize these constraints.

Qr[i] has to be equal to Q[i] when Z[i] is equal to one
Qr[i] has to be equal to 0 when Z[i] is null

Z is a vector containing boolean variables.

I already thought of this solution : Qr[i] = Q[i] * Z[i]
But because both Z and Q are variables, this solution isn't linear.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume $x \in [0,U]$ and $\delta \in \{0,1\}$, i.e. $x$ is a non-negative continuous variable and $\delta$ is a binary variable. Then $y=x\cdot \delta$ can be written as:

$$
\begin{align}
  &y \le \delta U\\
  &y \le x\\
  &y \ge x - U(1-\delta)\\
  &y \in [0, U]\\
\end{align}
$$